# Razor view not working ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

I working on `Login` in `AdminController` (in the `Admin` area).

Here is my `AccountController`:

```
using Sneaker.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Sneaker.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    [Area("Admin")]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        private UserManager<AppUserModel> _userManager;
        private SignInManager<AppUserModel> _signInManager;

        public AdminController(UserManager<AppUserModel> userManager, SignInManager<AppUserModel> signInManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }
        
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserModel user)
        {
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, user.Password, false, false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error");

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
        }        

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And the view for the `Login` action :

```
@model UserModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!---Coding By CoderGirl | www.codinglabweb.com--->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Login & Registration Form | CoderGirl</title>
    <!---Custom CSS File--->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
        <div class="login form">
            <header>Login</header>
            <form asp-action="Login" asp-controller="Admin">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="UserName" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Password" type="password" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know why the index action works correctly, but when I try to open the login form, the page show could not be found

[Here my route folder View][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHZ5D.png

And the index work so well but the login action cant be access (outside the Admin area the login action work normal)

Here my map controller route

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "areas",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
```

Can you guys know the problem? Many thanks

Comment: I don't know if modern ASP.NET tooling is expected to do this for you (I know it didn't before), but perhaps you just need `method="POST"` in the `<form>` tag?  The controller action is expecting a POST request, and the default method for a form is GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is just post method for Login action in Admin Controller,

so... how u want see login form my friend?
u need this :

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}
```

after that u can see login page but
but i think your login.cshtml have some problem too

```
<form asp-action="" asp-area="" asp-controller="" method="post"></form>
```

Comment: @NghĩaNghĩa We are all learning by making many mistakes
good luck bro